# How to convert text files to binary in an efficient way in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, binaryfiles

I have checked several methods for converting text files to binary and found some answers here as well. However, most of them confused me due to Unity .NET compatibility and I am also confused about the structure of how I convert text to binary.

I have a text file (exported point cloud) which holds positions of points in 3D space and color information like this:

`X         Y        Z colorvalues
-0.680891 -90.6809 0 204 204 204 255`

I was reading this to create meshes in run time with a script like this:

```
 string[] buffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < Area.nPoints; i++)
    {
        buffer = sr.ReadLine().Split();

        Area.AddPoint(new Vector3(float.Parse(buffer[0]), 
        float.Parse(buffer[1]), float.Parse(buffer[2])));
    }
```

This works but since I read line and split them it is quite slow and I have around 75 million lines(Points) in my text file. I found out that I can convert it to binary and reading would be faster which I did and it was a lot faster. However, now converting to binary part is quite slow I wanted to ask you about the way I converted.

```
void WriteValues()
{
    string[] buffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        buffer = sr.ReadLine().Split();
        for (int j = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            wr.Write(float.Parse(buffer[j]));
        }           
    }        
    wr.Close();
}
```

Then I read it with `BinaryReader.ReadSingle()` but this takes a lot more time than reading directly from the text because I again read the line and split it.

My question is could I read lets say next 1000 lines buffer it and then write instead of reading every line? Would it make a difference. If so how can I use stream once for every 1000 lines.

Also when I converted a line to binary how can I read every float in the line without splitting the string? Thanks in advance for any help!

I am trying to do this for visualizing a point cloud in my mobile phone using Augmented Reality. So I want to do the scan, export the point cloud, import it to Unity and create a mesh by using those points without triangulating but with my initial approach it take 15-18 minutes to import it. After converting to binary it takes less than 3 minutes which is okay. However, converting to binary takes a lot of time this time :)

Comment: how big is the file?

Comment: definitely don't read it line by line, either read it all, or read very large chunks of it

Comment: @KeithNicholas it is 3.41 GB

Comment: @KeithNicholas If i read it all it might cause memory issues because i also want to do this in my Android mobile phone.

Comment: is the data all the same format as the line of numbers in the question?

Comment: @Yes it is just position and color information of a point cloud. Actually it is .xyz format

Comment: so x y and a 32 bit color representation?

Comment: as binary, the file would be 858MB,  still quite big,  I'm picking compressed it might be a couple hundred MB perhaps... Id make your own binary format and use a streaming compression format

Comment: Yes x y z and color representation but i do not use color information because i color the point cloud based on density so only thing i am interested in these lines is first three float numbers in every line.

Comment: @AliKanat - where is the text file coming from? how and where is it generated?

Comment: I have edited the question. File is coming from a laser scanner it holds the positions of the points in 3D space. I am using those points to create a mesh and visualize it in my mobile with ARCore.

Comment: @AliKanat - if reading is slow, then reading, writing to a different file format and reading back from that file is going to be even slower... you are just adding more stuff to something that is already slow...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Yes that is exactly what happens now :) i thought if i can do reading and writing to binary in a better way which i can not do by reading from only text, that might make things better.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer i will try serialization and let you know.

Comment: @AliKanat - also added a bit about `BufferedStream` that might help... Sorry about the many edits. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: do you know what Area.AddPoint does?  I don't have Unity... but I made a file of similar size with random numbers and I can read it all in 30 seconds as text

Comment: 14 seconds now :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas - why does it matter? `Area.AddPoint(new Vector3(float.Parse(buffer[0]), float.Parse(buffer[1]), float.Parse(buffer[2])));` is not what he's asking help with... He's got to do that - whichever way the data is read...

Comment: It is an instance from a class i created. It has a property as a `Vector3` array. I just assign points to the array which is preallocated.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia  just curious as it seems the file reading done right isn't the most significant cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a reasonably quick way to read is with a buffered file stream.  Without the float parsing, the reading takes 14 ish seconds on my machine.... 74 seconds ish with float parsing  ( I just summed since I don't have unity to play with )

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
double sum = 0;
var fs = new FileStream("demo.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (var bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (var r = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    r.ReadLine();
    while (!r.EndOfStream)
    {
        var l = r.ReadLine();
        var split = l.Split();
        var x = float.Parse(split[0]);
        var y = float.Parse(split[1]);
        var z=float.Parse(split[2]);
        sum += x + y + z;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000M);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

out of interest I also changed the code to write the data out as a stream of floats ( in triplets)

read in with

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
double sum = 0;
var fs = new FileStream("demo.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (var bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (var r = new BinaryReader(bs))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 75000000; i++)
    {
        var x = r.ReadSingle();
        var y = r.ReadSingle();
        var z=r.ReadSingle();
        sum += x + y + z;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000M);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

takes ~ 9 seconds

just for completeness, I used the following code to generate demo files..

```
   var random = new Random();
    File.WriteAllText("demo.txt", "X         Y        Z colorvalues\r\n");
    using (var fs = new FileStream("demo.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    using (var writer = File.AppendText("demo.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 75000000; i++)
        {
            var x = (float) random.NextDouble() * 200;
            var y = (float) random.NextDouble() * 200;
            var z = (float) random.NextDouble() * 200;
            var c = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(n => random.Next(0, 255)).ToArray();
            writer.WriteLine($"{x} {y} {z} {c[0]} {c[1]} {c[2]} {c[3]}");
            bw.Write(x);
            bw.Write(y);
            bw.Write(z);
        }
}
```

Comment: I have commented out `Area` part but it is still slow. I have tried `BufferedStream` before but it was also slow. I do not know if this is a Unity issue because it is no where close to 74 seconds in my machine :)

Comment: hmmmmm, not sure, It has mono in the background right?

Comment: @AliKanat I just updated to a pure binary read and that was very quick

Comment: Yes it has mono in the background. I will try pure binary and let you know. Thanks a lot by the way for taking time to help me.

Comment: This is driving me crazy :) I commented everything and i just read lines from the file it takes 3.5 minutes without doing anything no split nothing  just reading with `StreamReader`.

Comment: thats really weird, its pointing to something else causing the slowness.

Comment: Today i found out what the problem is. It was because i was testing the code in Editor when i built the code for windows or Android it worked with similar time to yours.

Comment: ah ok, cool.... though still weird that you got that much of a slow down

Answer (score 1):

That might be silly question but why don't you scan & save directly into binary or .ply file? Or even scan & save into mesh or some voxelized-style mesh

You may also look up the approach used in [this](https://github.com/keijiro/Pcx) project, especially [PlyImporter.cs](https://github.com/keijiro/Pcx/blob/master/Assets/Pcx/Editor/PlyImporter.cs)

Comment: I can not export as binary or .ply in the software i am using and i have no chance of changing the software. Therefore, i have to construct the point cloud myself. I have no problem with creating the mesh or point cloud in unity. I can do it in seconds but the problem is reading the line and splitting it into floats. That takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If reading is slow, then reading, writing to a different file format and then reading back from that file is going to be even slower. You are just adding more actions to something that is already slow... Maybe you should look at how to change the way you do the reading from the text file.

If you are not familiar with how serialization/deserialization is done in C#, using the built in libraries, you should start by reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/

Here is a link to show how to implement binary serialization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2

However if you are not writing the initial file, you just need to write a custom deserializer (which is essentially what you have done - without implementing the relevant .NET patterns). Maybe try using a `BufferedStream` and see whether that help ie.:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, ..... ))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
        string s;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //your code   
        }
}
```

Also it is worth having a look at this library which can help you with this task: [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/) - Look at this example: https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/

Comment: My bottleneck for the issue is where i read and split. I am not sure how serializing would solve that issue.

Comment: @AliKanat - all that would be done by your serializer, so that you dont have to serialize/deserialize your data manually