# Reading from a text in Unity is a lot slower than C# console application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251269/how-to-convert-text-files-to-binary-in-an-efficient-way-in-c-sharp) question I have a text file in  this format with 75 million lines:

`X         Y        Z colorvalues
-0.680891 -90.6809 0 204 204 204 255`

I was reading from the file and the operation was really slow. After some discussion I realized the operation is slow only on Unity. I tested the following code:

```
StreamReader sr;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sr = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/PointCloud/DVS.txt");
    Debug.Log("Read is called");
    Read();
}

void Read()
{

    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine())!=null)
    {

    }
    Debug.Log("Read has ended");
}
```

It takes 3 minutes to just read from a txt file without any other operation. When I test it with C# application or with C++ it takes maximum 30 seconds. I am really curious what causes the issue. I would be happy if anyone can explain why this issue happens on Unity. Thanks!

Here is a photo of Profiler with a new Thread.

[image]

Comment: There are several reasons for this, 1 being c++ is actually way faster then c#.  Another being that Unity does alot of stuff in the background that your normal c# console application isn't.

Comment: I would be curious to the result if you made a new thread, and had that thread handle your reading operation how long that would take.

Comment: I initially did it in a new thread actually that takes same time. It is also long.

Comment: I'm curious where Unity3d's profiler thinks the time is being spent.

Comment: Unity uses a different garbage collector than desktop c#.   What happens to the performance if you set `Scripting.GarbageCollector.Mode = GarbageCollector.Mode.Disabled `?

Comment: I added ss of Profiler. I will check garbage collector mode now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i figured out what the problem is. I was testing these codes in Editor and in development built for some debugging. When i built it for Windows properly the reading was a lot faster and read all the lines in around 30 seconds.